# Why does my printer take so long to turn on?

Tags: printing, inkjet-printer

I've noticed over my ~20 year history in computing that (certainly home-market) printers are getting slower and slower to turn on as technology 'progresses' - by which I mean that they take longer and longer to do perform all kinds of miscellaneous grinding noises of dubious benefit as part of the startup procedure before they are ready to accept a job. I'm thinking here primary of inkjets, although lasers may be guilty too. For example, my [OfficeJet 8500](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&product=3752456) sometimes takes > 1 minute to start.

What kinds of things is my printer doing when I turn it on that cause whirring, grinding, and grunting, and does it really need to do them? Am I right that more "sophisticated" printers seem to take longer to do this?

Comment: its mostly caused by cleaning internal parts like the printing head.

Comment: I notice that too.  My 3 year old HP colour printer (a terrible buy) takes about 3 minutes to get ready.  It's ridiculously slow!

Comment: It's really just an attempt by the manufacturer to convince you that you bought a "smart" printer.  The "smarter" the device, the longer it takes to boot up, so they add a delay loop and have it make some odd noises.  Remember when TVs were "instant on"?

Answer (score 1):

All that grinding and whirring is the printer running through a check of its moving components.  The stepper motor is spun up to see if its working, it usually controls all the moving parts.  The stabilizer belt is spun back and forth to make sure its working properly and that the print head assembly is properly aligned.  The print head assembly checks to see if the the proper print cartridge is in - or drop it off if it isnt (all dependent on model).  The paper rollers are being spun to make sure they work properly and can grab a piece of paper.  All of this is usually when you first turn on the printer.  It is a one time check to make sure everything is good to go before you print.  A few seconds to check and give the "all clear" is a lot better than coming back to find your 200 page document was not printed properly.

As for the process is getting longer, I cant say I agree.  I remember my first inkjet printer took forever to start.  If anything, I would say the time is the same, or shorter.

Comment: I also notice lots of whirring and clicking when I print something after the printer has been idle for a while (I tend to use it at most once a week), even though I leave it turned on most of the time. I've noticed this with a number of different printers over the years, from different manufacturers (Canon and HP, I think). It always scares me because some of the sounds are similar to jammed components.

Answer (score 0):

After turning on the laser printer starts an all-out test equipment for serviceability. Includes stove, heats up to 200 degrees Celsius, or a little more. Scrolls for uniform heating of rotating elements next to the stove, to avoid problems with pulling the paper. Filling the cartridge checked and set in motion the print drum to drop a knife residual toner, if any. Downloadable fonts and postscript. Tested mechanical components.

In inkjet paranoia about health head cartridges. Regular time to come to their testing and cleaning.

I think the main issue in the resolution of the printer. Needle printer simply did not need to prepare for example), but printed and 9 or 24 pins)) This is somewhat different from the 600 ppi and above have a good printer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the other said.  Each new printer has more features some of those have to be verified:

- Does it support WiFi, if yes it takes time to attach to it and verify connectivity
- Does it support wired network, a few more seconds
- Does it have a USB port for fast printing? More time to mount and read the USB
- Does it have a fancy graphical screen?  More time to load and process the graphics on it
- Most printers take time to do memory checks
- Most printers have slow CPU
- Touchscreen? more drivers and checking
- Duplexing? Duplexer has to checked
- Ink levels are checked
- Check for paper jams

Comment: Consider using a bullet list instead of a code block that one has to horizontally scroll unnecessarily.